# instabug crashes when activity opened

Tags: android, instabug

Here's the beginning of the stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater
at com.instabug.library.InstabugFeedbackActivity.onViewCreated(InstabugFeedbackActivity.java:123)
at com.instabug.library.InstabugAnnotationScreen.onCreate(InstabugAnnotationScreen.java:109)
at com.instabug.library.InstabugFeedbackActivity.onCreate(InstabugFeedbackActivity.java:30)
```

Answer (score 1):

solution seems to be

compile 'com.instabug.library:instabugsupport:1.7.3'

(was pulling in 1.8-SNAPSHOT by default)